# How to permanently delete an abandoned pull request in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

We have an abandoned pull request which we would like to permanently remove. How can this be done? There doesn't seem to be a 'delete' or 'remove' option. Thanks.

Comment: This is an [under review feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365572/allow-deletion-of-pull-requests.html) for DevOps currently. It's currently not possible to delete a pull request, abandoned or not.

Comment: Update **2022-05-19**: Looks like it still has **not** been implemented yet...

Comment: It's Azure DevOps, it's been abandoned for years.

Comment: April 2023 - still not implemented. So much for being "customer-obsessed".

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> How to permanently delete an abandoned pull request in Azure DevOps?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I'm afraid there is no such way to permanently delete an abandoned pull request in Azure DevOps at this moment.

Microsoft thinks that data retention and traceability is important to a lot of our customers - it's not as simple as always providing CRUD operations for every artifact. But more and more customers are requesting delete pull requests, or at least the ability to delete abandoned pull requests.

Just like Spevacus comment, this feature is under Review, and [Microsoft replied](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365572/allow-deletion-of-pull-requests.html):

> Your suggestion has been queued up for prioritization. Feature
>   suggestions are prioritized based on the value to our broader
>   developer community and the product roadmap. We may not be able to
>   pursue this one immediately, but we will continue to monitor it up to
>   90 days for community input

You could vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough community votes and comments with reliable feedback, the product team members will take this feature request seriously.

Hope this helps.

Comment: > take this feature request seriously

Comment: my use case for this is that one of our developers committed a production password and created a pull request. and Now that password is visible under that abandoned PR in perpetuity because there's no way to delete. not even if the source branch is deleted.

Comment: exactly same situation as for @Nandun, I've reset to the previous commit, git history now is clean with no secrets visible, but you can always find it in the PR.
The only option now is to delete and re-create the repo.

Comment: Come on. Allow us to close a pull request gracefully rather than letting it stay in an abended state :P. Github (from Microsoft) allows it.

Answer (score 25):

While an abandoned pull request cannot currently be permanently deleted in Azure DevOps, it can be closed. The comment/update history will remain, but the pull request will not show up in the "Abandoned" list.

1. Delete the pull request's source branch if it still exists.
2. Create a new branch based on the main branch with the same name as the original source branch.
3. Reactivate the pull request
4. Close the pull request

The new status will be "Completed"

Comment: Thank you. It is a relief to see these 'completed' without an action being performed. "No merge was performed since [main] already included these changes."

Answer (score 3):

I also wanted to do this so that I wouldn't have an open pull request showing in open pull requests forever. So you can't delete the pull request, but at least you can get it marked as closed/completed. As a workaround until the delete feature is added you can do the following:

1. Create a temporary branch, let's say we call it "DeleteMe"
2. In your pull request, change the destination branch to DeleteMe
3. Complete the pull request.
4. In DeleteMe branch, if you want this updated with any new changes then you can make it updated to current. Otherwise just make any change to a file. You can add in a space on a comment for instance.
5. Create a new pull request to merge DeleteMe back into the original branch.
6. Complete the pull request and delete the DeleteMe branch.

Now the pull request will be closed/completed.

Answer (score 0):

My priority was to  prevent an inadvertent merge to Prod.

Hence you can:

- add yourself as reviewer, then Reject; Save
- as above, change the target branch to a dummy branch; Save
- place [DELETED} at start of the title; Save
- set the PR to Draft - that resets your rejected review

  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/sprint-143-update#draft-pull-requests
- or "Abandon" the PR